# Show personal email and calendar in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook

Is it possible to show a personal outlook email and outlook calendar on sharepoint?

As an `iframe` or a `web app` or something? **Not** a shared list or shared calendar....

Comment: I've no experience of using a personal outlook email in an iframe, but I have used other software in this way - for instance I put a map in an iframe.  I imagine the same would be possible with your email account. 
 Here is a link to a MS post which seems like it covers what you are looking to do: (https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2897680/how-to-set-up-exchange-on-the-web-to-access-exchange-server)

Comment: Well I want every user to get his/her own email in the sharepointpage. I cant see that article covering that.